# Can players move tokens in Mipui without being an admin of the map that those tokens are placed on?

Tags: tools, battle-map, mipui

Hello I was wondering if there is a way for players to interact with a map, without being considered a creator/admin of a map, so that they can move their tokens without being able to see through *the fog of war* (for example).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Also check out this related question: [Can I move tokens in Mipui?](/questions/116941)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. There isn't any way in Mipui for non-editors to change *anything* on the map.

The work-around I've seen is to ask the editor(s) to do that for you, relying on the coordinates - the x/y values you see when hovering over squares - to identify specific squares.